# How to convert Ascii lists to text?

Tags: python, list, text, ascii

```
aList = [[ord(ch) for ch in word] for word in wordlist]
bList = [[x - offset for x in word] for word in aList]
cList = [[x + 94 for x in word if x < 33] for word in bList]
print(cList)
for i in cList:
    text = chr(i)
    print(text)
```

This is the end of a program that I made to encrypt and decrypt text once I have turned it into its correct ASCII value. I don't know how to convert that value into text without getting the error:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)
```

Comment: I used to do stuff like that in BASIC on 8-bit CPUs ... but I'm sure you're overcomplicating this particular problem.  Q: What is the source data?  A text file?  Q: What output do you need?  Do you simply want to read the contents of the text file into a Python string?  Please explain in a bit more detail exactly what you're trying to do...

Comment: thank you for editing your post to clarify your question.  Q: Is [str()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) the thing you were looking for?  If so, please be sure to "upvote" and "accept" David the third's reply.

Comment: Please add enough of the surrounding code to be able to run this code. As it is, we must make up a lot of detail to merely get *anything*, which may obscure the problem that you are having.

Comment: As I guess, your code's goal is to print only those letters (in uppercase) from the list of words to the console (in lowercase form), if offset is 60 (e.g.). Please clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element in `cList` is itself a python list, so you can't pass it to `chr`. Instead, you need to also iterate over every element in every list in `cList`:

```
aList = [[ord(ch) for ch in word] for word in wordlist]
bList = [[x - ofset for x in word] for word in aList]
cList = [[x + 94 for x in word if x < 33] for word in bList]
print(cList)
for arr in cList:
    for i in arr:
        text = chr(i)
        print(text)
```

Comment: Thabk you, this only works if you put str(list) infront though.

Answer (score 0):

The `str` function is a function designed to be able to turn anything into a string. If you have a list called `mylist`, you can convert it to a string like this:

```
str(mylist)
```

at which point you can do whatever you want with it. See [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/str) for more information on `str`.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not what OP is trying to do. Applying str to a list of characters produces something like `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Answer (score 0):

You start out with a list of words (`List`). Each of the words is a single string. Then you split each word into individual characters, convert them to integers, and do some transformations (`bList` and `cList`). At this point you end up with a list of lists of characters.

If your goal is to convert each nested list back into a string, the simplest way is probably with `str.join`:

```
dList = [str.join(chr(c) for c in row) for row in cList]
for word in dList:
    print(word)
```